# Compile with Clang and G++

Tags: c++, g++, clang

I was trying to compile Kevin Beason's [SmallPT](https://www.kevinbeason.com/smallpt/#mods) on Mac. I deleted the lines using OpenMP, so it will be a simple C++ program that uses no external libraries other than regular C++ libraries.

I tried to compile with Clang like below, but got weird error:

```
% clang -x c++ smallpt.cpp -o smallest

... (Irrelevant warnings are not pasted here)

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "operator delete[](void*)", referenced from:
    _main in smallpt-520b67.o
  "operator new[](unsigned long)", referenced from:
    _main in smallpt-520b67.o
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      _main in smallpt-520b67.o
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in smallpt-520b67.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

However, it I use G++ as instructed on SmallPT's website, it works:

```
% g++ smallpt.cpp -o smallpt
```

---

My question is, how are the two command uses were different, since on Mac, the call to G++ is actually handled by Clang.

Comment: g++ must be explicitly supplying the C++ runtime library to the linker, but `clang` is not.

Comment: It turned out I need to use **Clang++** like this: `% clang++ smallpt.cpp`. But I wonder how is the `-x c++` parameter with Clang differs from this.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't get it, I didn't specify anything for G++, nor for Clang.

Comment: @jackxujh same as with `gcc -x c++` and `g++`: when linking, you do not get the C++ library linked in automatically. `clang` behaves as `gcc` and `clang++` behaves as `g++` for as much as possible.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik so to use `-x c++` with Clang or GCC, do I also need to specify the library for linking?